# ¿Por qué no se puede potenciar correctamente mi codigo?

Tags: c++

el problema que tengo es que al ejecutar mi código, todo sale bien, hasta que se llega a la parte en la que tiene que potenciarme la discriminante de mi ecuación, no me sale el resultado que me debería salir, e intente con pow y con sqrt, pero ninguno de los dos me da el resultado para que la ecuación me salga correctamente, si alguien sabe el problema le agradecería mucho su ayuda, muchas gracias.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "math.h"

// Las raíces reales de la expresión ax^2 + bx + c = 0 se obtienen a través de la fórmula:

// x = -b+- "raíz" b^2 - 4(a)(c)/2(a)

//Haga el programa para calcular las raíces reales, de ser posible, de una ecuación de segundo grado.

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    float A;
    float B;
    float C;
    float DIS;
    float X1;
    float X2;

    cout<< "DA VALORES A SUS VARIABLES:"<< endl;
    cout<< "VARIABLE A:";
    cin>> A;
    cout<< "VARIABLE B:";
    cin>> B;
    cout<< "VARIABLE C:";
    cin>> C;

    DIS = (B*B) - 4 * A * C;
    cout<< "MOSTRAR DISCRIMINANTE DE LA ECUACION:"<< DIS<< endl;

    if (DIS >= 0)
    {
        X1=((-B) + pow(DIS, 0.5) /2*A);
        X2= ((-B) - pow(DIS,0.5) /2*A);
        cout<< "SUS RAICES REALES SON:"<< endl;
            cout<< X1 << endl;
            cout<< X2 << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Deberías indicar cuál es el valor de los parámetros, qué valor esperas obtener y qué valor obtienes. Además, sería conveniente que separaras la expresión en varias para saber dónde te sale la diferencia. Y por último, que estudiaras *el orden de precedencia de los operadoeres*.

Comment: Hola, no creo que las funciones estén valga la redundancia funcionando mal. Hace una prueba de pow dentro o fuera del IF con números constantes y verifica. El error puede ser, sí es que llega bien dentro del IF por las precedencias y algún paréntesis mas necesario.

Comment: esta mal la formula.. ((-B) + pow(DIS, 0.5) /2*A); por precedencia de operadores, no esta diviendo la suma de b + la raiz cuadrada, si no que primero esta dividiendo la raiz por 2, luego la multiplica por a, y luego hace la suma... cosa que no es lo que queres...

Comment: Aaaaaa okok, entiendo lo que me dices, pero no se como formularla correctamente, tendría que primero hacer la raíz y luego la división , correcto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error es matemático es recomendable usar paréntesis siempre para asegurarnos del resultado deseado.

Por lo que te sugiero estos cambios:

```
X1=((-B) + pow(DIS, 0.5)) /2*A; 
X2= ((-B) - pow(DIS,0.5)) /2*A;
```

Otro punto es que para la raiz cuadrada deberia utilizar sqrt.

```
X1=((-B) + sqrt(DIS)) /2*A;
X2= ((-B) - sqrt(DIS)) /2*A;
```

Las dos formas son validas.

Aqui dejo la formula para que sirva de guía:[image: Formula general]

Comment: si yo también revisé mi código e hice lo que me dijiste, pero tengo un libro de algoritmos, y cuando hago los ejemplos que hay ahí la discriminante de la ecuación me sale correcta pero las raices ( X1 Y X2) no aparecen como esta en el libro, y  es por eso que no se cual es el error.